# Python function within a loop iterating over text files only works on the first file

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm writing a simple script which loops over some text file and uses a function which should replace some string looking in a .csv file (every row has the word to replace and the word which I want there)
Here is my simple code:

```
import os
import re
import csv

def substitute_tips(table, tree_content):
    count = 0
    for l in table:
        print("element of the table", l[1])
        reg_tree = re.search(l[1],tree_content)
        if reg_tree is not None:
            #print("match in the tree: ",reg_tree.group())
            tree_content = tree_content.replace(reg_tree.group(), l[0])
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print("Not found: ",l[1])
            tree_content = tree_content
    print("Substitutions done: ",count)        
    return(tree_content)

path=os.getcwd()
table_name = "162_table.csv"
table = open(table_name) 
csv_table = csv.reader(table, delimiter='\t')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".tree"):
            print(Fore.GREEN + "Working on treefile", name)
            my_tree = open(name, "r")
            my_tree_content = my_tree.read()
            output_tree = substitute_tips(csv_table, my_tree_content)
            output_file = open(name.rstrip("tree") + "SPECIES_NAME.tre", "w")
            output_file.write(output_tree)    
            output_file.close()
        else:
            print(Fore.YELLOW + name ,Fore.RED + "doesn't end in .tree")
```

It's probably very easy, but I'm a newbie.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing it only updates '162_table.csv' since that's what csv_table has been set to.  You probably want to move that line into your loop and read file

Comment: Thanks, you're right, so easy :) Sorry to bother :D

Answer (score 0):

The `files` list returned by `os.walk` contains only the file names rather than the full path names. You should join `root` with the file names instead to be able to open them:

Change:

```
my_tree = open(name, "r")
...
output_file = open(name.rstrip("tree") + "SPECIES_NAME.tre", "w")
```

to:

```
my_tree = open(os.path.join(root, name), "r")
...
output_file = open(os.path.join(root, name.rstrip("tree") + "SPECIES_NAME.tre"), "w")
```

Comment: Moving the .csv reading worked! The loop was correctly looping over each file but the .csv table reading step must be within the loop. Thanks anyway!